Debian upgrade: How can one verify all packages that apt-get full-upgrade wanted to install have indeed been installed (ie after interrupted upgrade)?
I upgraded from Debian11/KDE to Debian12 by running sudo apt-get upgrade --without-new-pkgs, freeing up some disk space on the partition (this can also break the upgrade for some users!), then running sudo apt-get full-upgrade. The upgrade went like this:

After it installed many packages, I got an error (details below) so it returned Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1). I solved this problem (details below)
Then had to run sudo apt --fix-broken install which upgraded libgmic1 and gimp-gmic and removed a handful of packages
Since disk space was running low on the root partition, I freed up disk space by running sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* (the cache of packages just installed took up a lot of disk space). The error interrupting the upgrade was handy since it prevented the upgrade from failing due to disk space running out.
Then I ran sudo apt-get full-upgrade again and it completed without errors. It first had to download the remaining packages again since I deleted the cache.

According to /var/log/apt/history.log no packages were removed/installed between these three commands. In that log it says "plasma-systemmonitor:amd64 (5.27.5-2, automatic)" should have been installed by the apt-get full-upgrade command (it lists it next to "Install: "). However, after all this (upgrading to Debian12) I noticed that this particular package was not installed and installed this specific package.
Now I'm wondering if maybe more packages that originally were supposed to get installed have not been installed. How can verify that all of them have been installed and that the Debian upgrade is complete without any essential/core packages missing? Obviously, apt-get upgrade should show if any dependencies of installed packages are missing or if any upgrades are still available but it neither shows packages that were originally supposed to get installed nor info about which default Debian12 or KDE packages are currently not installed.

Details: the output/error I got was:
Setting up usrmerge (37~deb12u1) ...

FATAL ERROR:
Both /lib/udev/mtp-probe and /usr/lib/udev/mtp-probe exist.

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

E: usrmerge failed.
dpkg: error processing package usrmerge (--configure):
 installed usrmerge package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 usrmerge

I solved this problem by moving the older files out of their directories (use ls -l /lib/udev/mtp-probe and /usr/lib/udev/mtp-probe to check what the older file is) until I could successfully run /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge.
Upgrades can also break because of disk space running out but fractional upgrades where each step only requires less disk space (or dynamically below the available space) is a separate subject.

To be 100% clear, the log of the first full-upgrade command contains plasma-systemmonitor:amd64 in the list of packages to be installed, but the log of the second one doesn’t?

Good question, yes the second one doesn't contain it. The only other two mentions of "plasma-systemmonitor" in that history.log file that contains the output of all of the relevant commands are where I installed it using apt-get install after upgrading to Deb12.

If running dpkg --configure -a after an upgrade produces no output, everything should be set up correctly.

Made a bugreport for the missing plasma-systemmonitor package. StephenKitt, @Panki to be clear I'd like to see which packages are missing compared to the default of Debian with KDE. How it differs to the packages of a PC where that is newly installed.

@Panki everything that was installed will be set up correctly, but that’s not the question here. The problem is that if you run apt dist-upgrade, and that upgrade fails part of the way through, a subsequent apt dist-upgrade will restart from the current state of the system and not the state before the first upgrade attempt. The difference is that any package newly-installed as part of the initial upgrade (because an upgraded package added a new dependency) should have its recommended dependencies installed, but if the upgrade fails in between, the recommended packages won’t be installed …

… in the second upgrade attempt.

Didn't know that, that sounds like quite a problem especially if there is no way to check...is there an issue for this? I think it's another reason for why a stepwise upgrade that I just suggested here would be really useful. Note: usually, the upgrade fails because of too little disk space; I think the usrmerge setup shouldn't have caused an error but pause the upgrade to let the user solve the issue until it retries setting up usrmerge.

@mYnDstrEAm Instead of a stepwise upgrade, why not support an atomic upgrade.  This would solve the issue during dist-upgrades etc  If one package/flatpak/whatever fails, the entire transaction is rolled back as if the entire upgrade never took place.  This would allow the user to "fix" the broken item, retry, repeat until all the items were correctly installed in one go.  It would also alleviate the issue Stephen described to Panki
